# Adjust height/position of multiple listviews so that content is aligned

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, layout, grid

I'm designing an application where I need to position multiple `ListView`s in a way that the content is aligned like this (simplified):
[image]

## What I have:

- The outer layout is a `Grid` (black)
- The `ListView` (grey) on the left has a small header
- The `ListView`s (grey) on the right are generated in an `ItemsControl` and have a fairly large header (vertical text). Also, they are part of a `UserControl` with additional content above them (not shown here)

## What I want:

- The contents (red) of all `ListView`s should be aligned and start at the same height (blue line)
- I DON'T want to set the headers (green) to have the same height, because that would waste much space due to the large height difference.

The only solution I can think of is to calculate the height of all elements above the `ListView`s and the height of the headers, and then change the height of the upper `Grid` row so that the contents start at the same height. But that seems rather tedious, error prone and clumsy to me.

Is there a more elegant solution, maybe involving `SharedGroupSize` or binding the height property?

## XAML for the overall layout:

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <local:SomeControl1 x:Name="generalSettingsControl" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FirstList}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name"
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CombinedName}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="ID"
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

        <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Samples}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:ListViewUserControl DataContext="{Binding }" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
```

## XAML for the ListViews in the ItemsControl :

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="verticalGridViewColumnHeader" TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}" FontWeight="Bold" Width="60"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
                        </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Text="Placeholder (TODO)" Grid.Column="0" />
    <ListView x:Name="lvMeasurementsEdit"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Measurements}"
              Grid.Column="0"
              Grid.Row="2">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Value 1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value1}"
                                HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource verticalGridViewColumnHeader}" Width="Auto" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Value 2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value2}"
                                HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource verticalGridViewColumnHeader}" Width="Auto" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Please attach relevant XAML that will help as an starting point.

Comment: @codeDom Done, I hope it is helpful.

Comment: It's still not enough, attach relevant C# code.

Comment: There is no C# code, those are both Views with no code-behind. I don't think the ViewModels are of relevance

Comment: I came up with a solution that works in a simpler layout, but it is not beautiful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39035367/391338